# OpenGL mapped memory not updating

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

I have a code like this:

```
glNamedBufferStorage(atlas, capacity, nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT | GL_MAP_READ_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT | GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT);
mappedMemory = glMapNamedBufferRange(atlas, 0, cap, GL_MAP_READ_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT | GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT);

GLint cnt = 0;
gpu->glNamedBufferSubData(atlas, count.offset, count.size, &cnt);

glBindBufferRange(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 0, atlasId, count.offset, count.size);
glBindBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, atlasId, data.offset, data.size);
glDispatchCompute(x, y, z);
glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);
sync = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
while(true) {
  GLenum v = glClientWaitSync(sync, GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT, 0);
  isFinished = (v == GL_ALREADY_SIGNALED) || (v == GL_CONDITION_SATISFIED);
  if(isFinished)
    break;
}

GLint count = mappedMemory[count.offset];
Data *ddata = mappedMemory + data.offset;
```

And shader like this:

```
layout(binding = 0, offset = 0) uniform atomic_uint count;
layout(std430, binding = 0) writeonly buffer Data {
    uint data[];
};
const uint recordID = atomicCounterIncrement(count);
data[recordID] = some data;
```

When I run this code, it sometimes happens that the `ddata` is not filled completely when I try to read it. Resp. `count` shows more record that what I read from data. For checking, I pre-fill the data memory with some arbitrary values (using `glNamedBufferSubData`) and then check the memory against that. And indeed, at some random point in the `ddata` (sometimes right from index `0`, sometimes later), I stop reading the right data and start getting the original pre-filled values. Tested on Radeon 5700 XT.

Am I missing something here? That memory barrier is just for checking, since the memory is mapped as coherent the fence sync should be enough.

EDIT: I even tried adding `glFinish` right after the memory barrier, still getting the same behavior.

EDIT: it rather seems that the atomic counter was causing the problems. I've reworked the code into using atomicAdd over a SSBO instead of atomic counters and haven't encountered the bug since.

Comment: did you try [glFlushMappedBufferRange](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFlushMappedBufferRange.xhtml)

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi I'm not mapping the buffer for writing, but for reading only. For the data upload, I'm using `glBuferSubData`.

Comment: Code looks OK to me, I wouldn't be surprised if you ran into a driver bug in this area.

Comment: @derhass Oh hey derhass :) It looks like a driver bug to me indeed :/ In further testing, I started getting some ridiculous values from the atomic counter. I switched from atomic counter buffers to standard SSBO with using atomicAdd and the problem seems to have gone away.